# formbuilder angular 9 - problem with date validator

Tags: angular

I have a task to divided 2 message for datetime input:

- Date is require
- Out of date (like 30/02/2023 is not a valid date)

But the problem is when I use validator with formbuilder. The date return is validate before I click on the button submit. So when I click on the submit button the date always return null if it not valid (it mean I can not set 2 different condition because 2 condition is the same null value). So I can not setError for 2 message control in formbuilder when click on submit button.

**Library**

`import * as dateFormat from "dateformat";`

**.ts**

```
    updateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  createForm() {
    let now = new Date();
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      date: [
        dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd"),
        [Validators.required],
      ],

    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm()
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.updateForm.value.date)
    //alway null if date not valid
  }
```

**.html**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control input is-primary" formControlName="ngayApDung"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.date.errors }" cdkFocusInitial />
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.date.errors" class="help is-danger">
    <div *ngIf="f.date.errors.required" translate>
        date is required
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code in order to reproduce the error

Comment: @KostasNitaf I just update code

Comment: Could you please add your HTML and the import of the `dateFormat` ?

Comment: @KostasNitaf yes I just update html and library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTML input element` has a `validityState` class with many attributes.
The `badInput` attribute is `true` when you put a wrong date.

[image]

[image]

So you can achieve what you want by adding an extra helper function:

**Firstly add a new helper variable**

```
badInput: boolean = false;
```

**Form has only the required Validation**

```
let now = new Date();
this.updateForm = new FormGroup({
      date_new: new FormControl(now, [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
    });
```

**add a new helper function**

```
check(e: any){
  const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (target.validity.badInput){
    this.badInput = target.validity.badInput 
  }
  else{
    this.badInput = false
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<input
      type="date"
      class="form-control input is-primary"
      formControlName="date_new"
      [(ngModel)]="now"
      cdkFocusInitial
      formtarget="date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
      (keyup)="check($event)"
      />

  <div *ngIf="updateForm.controls['date_new'].errors && !badInput">Please enter a date
</div>
  <div *ngIf="updateForm.controls['date_new'].errors && badInput">Invalid date
</div>
```

You need `updateForm.controls['date_new'].errors` to display divs only on errors and the `badInput` changes after the change of the `HTMLInputElement`

Comment: the problem is not validate date. The problem is 2 case: (out of date) and (required) is return one is false or null. I need it separate in 2 diffirent case so I can set each have own notification

Comment: out of date like 30/2/2023 display: date is not valid and if they clear date input then submit, it display date is required. Like that

Comment: ok! Now i fully understand your question... let me rewrite my answer.

Comment: yeah, thank you so much. May I have your social media contact? so that I can make new friends and learn more knowledge from you.

Comment: I have edited my answer check to see if works for you. I have no social :) only stackoverflow cu around

Comment: oh thank you, I don't know date input event has validity, that great. It works perfect.